# Eloquent Javascript: DOM Animation snippet

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, recursion, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to understand everything that is happening in this little code example in [Eloquent Javascript: The Document Object Model (Chapter 13)](http://eloquentjavascript.net//13_dom.html), but I'm not clear on where exactly the value for "time" is being passed into the animate() function before the function itself gets passed into requestAnimationFrame(). What exactly am I missing here?

```
<p style="text-align: center">
  <img src="img/cat.png" style="position: relative">
</p>

<script>
  var cat = document.querySelector("img");
  var angle = 0, lastTime = null;
  function animate(time) {
    if (lastTime != null)
      angle += (time - lastTime) * 0.001;
    lastTime = time;
    cat.style.top = (Math.sin(angle) * 20) + "px";
    cat.style.left = (Math.cos(angle) * 200) + "px";
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
</script>
```

Comment: `time` will be supplied by the implementation of [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Parameters).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. So I looked it up. Just to make sure that I understand correctly, it's DOMHighResTimeStamp that requestAnimationFrame passes into the callback, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute this line: `requestAnimationFrame(animate);`, the function `animate` will be called inside `requestAnimationFrame` and will get the `time` variable passed as an argument. Something like this (narrowed and rough):

```
function requestAnimationFrame(callback) {
    var time = getTime();
    callback(time); //Where callback is your `animate` function
};
```

Of course that `requestAnimationFrame` does not look at all like the function above, but this is just to illustrate where `time` comes from.

As per the documentation:

> The callback method is passed a single argument, a
>   DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time when callbacks
>   queued by requestAnimationFrame begin to fire. Multiple callbacks in a
>   single frame, therefore, each receive the same timestamp even though
>   time has passed during the computation of every previous callback's
>   workload. This timestamp is a decimal number, in milliseconds, but
>   with a minimal precision of 1ms (1000 µs).

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Great example, explanation, and source reference. I think I understand now. Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

**It's not being passed in beforehand**.

The line `function animate(time) {` doesn't call anything: instead, it *creates* a function named `animate`, which takes in a single argument called `time`.

The specification for `requestAnimationFrame` states that the callback always gets passed a single argument, which equals the number of milliseconds (or fractions thereof) since the page first loaded. So `time` doesn't get passed in before the function gets passed to `requestAnimationFrame`: instead, **it gets passed in every time `requestAnimationFrame` sets up its call to the callback**.

Comment: Is it passing in DOMHighResTimeStamp? I just want to make sure I understand clearly. Thanks for your help, so far.

Comment: It's passing in `DOMHighResTimeStamp`, yes. That's the *type* of the thing that `requestAnimationFrame` passes to its callback: JavaScript can do that with a plain old `Number`, but other languages might use something else.  It's not the *name* of the callback argument, though; the callback decides what the name will be.